# Vowel counter script not executing

Tags: python

```
vowel = "aeiou"
for i in range(0:len(s)):
    if s[i] in vowel == True
    count += 1
print("Number of vowels: "+str(count))
```

The above code doesn't throw any errors in Spyder. I am taking an online course, s is a predefined variable which contains a string. Here I defined s as "big black car"
I have to count the vowels in the string. 
When I press enter after typing the code in, I am moved to the next line, nothing happens, I am prompted for more input.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work by changing `range(0:len(s))` with `range(0,len(s))`?

Comment: Don't you need to indent `count += 1`? And aren't you missing a `:` at the end of if statement?

Comment: Get rid of the `0:`, replace the `== True` with a `:`, and indent the `count += 1` 4 spaces to the right.

Comment: You can also replace the `+str(count)` with `, count`...

Comment: And you can in fact replace the entire `if` clause with `count += s[i] in vowel`.

Comment: Or replace the entire `for` clause with `count = sum([s[i] in vowel for i in range(len(s))])`.

Comment: Or the entire code with `print("Number of vowels: ", sum([s[i] in vowel for i in range(len(s))]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code for you:

```
s="big black car"
vowel = "aeiou"
count = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
  if s[i] in vowel:
    count += 1
print("Number of vowels: "+str(count))
```

Note: First of all, you should use range `(len(s))`. Second thing is that `s[i] in vowel == True` will return False. You can easy check it in python console.

```
>>> 'a' in 'a'
True
>>> 'a' in 'a' == True
False
>>> ('a' in 'a') == True
True
```

According to my best knowledge Python firstly execute `'a' == True` that gives False, then execute `'a' in False`. That's why condition is False. Extra parentheses fix that problem.

EDIT: tripleee point that you can use range(len(s)) :).

Comment: `range(0, len(s))` is equivalent to `range(len(s))`

Comment: Thank you! that helps me out a lot

Comment: I didn't really understand why 'a' in 'a' == True returned false, but I hope I get that with practice

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the following:

1. Get rid of the `0:`
2. Replace the `== True` with a `:`
3. Indent the `count += 1` 4 spaces to the right

So your code should look as follows:

```
vowel = "aeiou"
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] in vowel:
        count += 1
print("Number of vowels: "+str(count))
```

You can further reduce it to:

```
vowel = "aeiou"
for i in range(len(s)):
    count += s[i] in vowel
print("Number of vowels: "+str(count))
```

And then further reduce it to:

```
vowel = "aeiou"
count = sum([s[i] in vowel for i in range(len(s))])
print("Number of vowels: "+str(count))
```

And then further reduce it to:

```
vowel = "aeiou"
print("Number of vowels: "+str(sum([s[i] in vowel for i in range(len(s))])))
```

And then further reduce it to:

```
vowel = "aeiou"
print("Number of vowels: ", sum([s[i] in vowel for i in range(len(s))]))
```

And then further reduce it to:

```
print("Number of vowels: ", sum([s[i] in "aeiou" for i in range(len(s))]))
```